# Windows 8 application online data

Tags: javascript, windows, html, winjs

I want to create an application for Windows 8 using HTML/CSS and JavaScript. It is a game and after playing, you have the opportunity to send your score. You also can view all the scores sent by other players.

Where should I store all the scores so they can be accessed from any device? How could I implement this using WinJS?

Comment: This is far too broad, and you're basically asking for a complete tutorial which isn't a good match for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using HTML/JavaScript directly, then I recommend you use **Azure Mobile Services** or **Buddy.com**. Azure Mobile Services is gaining a lot of traction and fits in very nicely with Windows apps for sure. It's a little bit lower level than Buddy.com, so it will give you more power. Buddy.com sort of packages and simplifies a lot of things for you and is a good fit for social games like it sounds like you're talking about.
You can checkout my codeshow project at http://codeshow.codeplex.com if you want to get some general "how to" on HTML/JS apps and you can feel free to contact me if I can help you get started.
Have fun!